# Cognito - How to get a user based on forget password code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a forget password flow in my app.
So I started with:

```
val secret = getSigned64BaseContent(cognitoAppSecret, (email + cognitoAppId).getBytes(), HMAC_SHA256)
val forgotPassword = new ForgotPasswordRequest()
  .withUsername(email)
  .withClientId(cognitoAppId)
  .withSecretHash(secret)
client.forgotPassword(forgotPassword)
```

This will result in an email sent to the user. The email will contain a url to my app that will look something like this:

```
https://my.app.com/forgetPassword?token={code}
```

When the user will click on the url, I want to retrieve the user related to this code and continue from there by redirecting him to a screen with the ability to change password, and then complete the flow with `ConfirmForgotPasswordRequest`.

The question is, how can I get the user based on the code?
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito doesn't provide such an API to retrieve a user based on verification code. Not sure if this is a valid workaround, but can't you add the necessary information to the URL you generate?

Comment: Yes this is what I did. The problem was that I had to replace the current flow that worked with Stormpath seamlessly...anyway thanks.